Enable wildcard redirect_uri and disable code verification
I am using Django OAuth toolkit in a intentionally vulnerable application. I am painting a scenario in which for example I there is a client application with redirect_uri abc.com.
I want to show to the user that in OAuth 2.0 if the redirect_uri is not specifically well taken care of the attacker can manipulate and redirect it to their own server.
In this case, if the attacker sends a link to the victim with redirect_uri, they will be able to receive the victim's authorization code.
Now, my first question is that I cannot see wildcard URI being possible in the OAuth toolkit. Is there any way I can enable it? Otherwise, I have to add evil.com to the allowed redirect_uri section of the app, which is not a valid scenario.
Similar to this one, if the attacker receives the authorization code after redirecting the user to attacker.com. From the authorization code, I cannot get the token as the OAuth toolkit also verifies the redirect_uri once the code is generated. Is there any way to bypass that so that the access token should be easily gerneateable without validation on redirect_uri?
May be I have made a bad decision regarding choice of the toolkit, I mean, the RFC does not say to store the authorization_code with redirect_uri in the database and then matches with during token generation process.

"the RFC does not say to store the authorization_code with redirect_uri in the database" - but even without that, the redirect_uri used when you exchange the code for a token must match one of those configured for the application. And no, I don't think you can use wildcards - those would increase the possibility of misconfiguration, that would leave it vulnerable to exactly the attack vector you're describing.

@CBroe yes that is fine, my quesition is that the RFC does not say that we cannot use wildcards. so to demonstrate possible weak configuration we can use the wildcard, if it is supported by the toolkit.

"I mean, the RFC does not say to store the authorization_code with redirect_uri in the database" - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.3 says, "redirect_uri: REQUIRED, if the "redirect_uri" parameter was included in the          authorization request as described in Section 4.1.1, and their values MUST be identical." - note that last part, the redirect_uri MUST be identical to the value used in the authorization request. (Where you store it, if necessary, is of course up to you, that's not for such an RFC to specify.)

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-3.1.2.2: "The authorization server SHOULD require the client to provide the complete redirection URI (the client MAY use the "state" request parameter to achieve per-request customization). If requiring the registration of the complete redirection URI is not possible, the authorization server SHOULD require the registration of the URI scheme, authority, and path (allowing the client to dynamically vary only the query component of the redirection URI when requesting authorization)." [...]

[...] - not mentioning any possibility of wildcards here either, only that that the whole query string part might be dynamic, if necessary. Of course those are SHOULDs and not MUSTs - but I don't think it would have made much sense for the makers of the django toolkit, to not follow those "strong suggestions".
